# better way to see if file has certain extention

Tags: php

I'm doing this right now in my code to see if a file name has the extension `.txt`, but I think it basically checks if it **contains** `.txt` and not necessarily **ends with** `.txt`. Does php have a better way to do extension checking instead of using `strpos`?

```
strpos($filename,'.txt') !== false
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can allow multiple extensions by adding to the array.

```
$allowed = array('txt');

if (in_array(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed)){
    // Has the correct file extension
}
```

or a simpler version which allows only txt extensions could be:

```
if (pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'txt'){
    // Has the correct file extension
}
```

Comment: And `end(explode('.',strtolower($file)))` is much more readable than `pathinfo(...PATHINFO_EXTENSIN)`...is it? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function to get the extension of the file:

```
$info = pathinfo($pathToFile);
$ext = $info['extension'];
```

and then check if the extension is one of the allowed:

```
$validExtensions = array("txt", "doc");
if (in_array($ext, $validExtensions) {
    //more code
}
```

Comment: @MarkBaker I use explode() because you can do it all on one line.. PS: Your missing a $

Comment: @Jleagle: P.S. you're missing a `'` and an `e`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code, it couldn't get any better:

```
$ext = pathinfo('test.txt', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Hopefully he's got PHP 5.2 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: You've had almost two years to read our [formatting FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), or to learn how to use the controls in the post box. Also, the best questions have accompanying descriptions/explanations.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal will take care of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

strpos is okay, you have to just keep in mind that you need not first but last dot.
and use `strrpos()`, note the double "r".